# Encriptar datos desde query en PHP

Tags: php, mysql

En el siguiente codigo inserto los datos y no esta siendo encriptado

```
$sentencia = $conn->prepare("insert into usuarios values(null,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,PASSWORD(?),?)");
    $sentencia->bindParam(1,$dni);
    $sentencia->bindParam(2,$nombre);
    $sentencia->bindParam(3,$ap);
    $sentencia->bindParam(4,$fec);
    $sentencia->bindParam(5,$mail);
    $sentencia->bindParam(6,$pro);
    $sentencia->bindParam(7,$loc);
    $sentencia->bindParam(8,$pass);
    $sentencia->bindParam(9,$tipo);
    $sentencia->execute();
```

Lo he comprobado manualmente desde base de datos y no sale el mismo código.
Este es mi archivo donde se crea el pass.

```
$("#enviar").click(function(){
        tipo = $("#tipo").val();
        nombre = $("#nombre").val();
        apellido = $("#apellidos").val();
        dni = $("#dni").val();
        fec = $("#fecha").val();
        mail = $("#correo").val();
        loc = $("#localidad").val();
        pro = $("#provincia").val();
        var pass = Pass();
        alert(pass);
        if(okapellidos && okdni && okemail && okfecha && oklocalidad && oknombre &&  okprovincia){
            $.post("./php/insertar.php",{nombre:nombre,apellidos:apellido,dni:dni,fec:fec,pass:pass,mail:mail,loc:loc,pro:pro,tipo:tipo},function(data){
                alert(data);
            });
        }


    });
function Pass(){
    var cadena = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    var num ="0123456789";
    an1 = num.length-2;
    an = cadena.length-4;
    var palabra = cadena.substr(Math.floor(Math.random()*an),4);
    palabra += num.substr(Math.floor(Math.random()*an1),2);
    return palabra;



}
```

Comment: Hola buenas tarde verifica la longitud del campo en la base de datos porque te lo puede estar cortando si la longitud es menor si quieres prueba con un **texto** de longitud **0** el cual es ilimitado

Comment: Ya he comprobado que eso no es.Tengo varchar(50) y la encriptacion se me queda en 40.

Comment: Imprime el contenido de la variable **pass** antes de hacer la inserción en la base de datos para ver si esta pasando el valor correcto

Comment: creo que el fallo es por que la creo aleatoriamente en jquery. Y no debe llegar igual.

Comment: intenta ver la consulta coloca esta linea despues del execute var_dump ($sentencia->queryString);  vas a ver que te esta generando el query

Comment: me devuelve el insert tal cual le tengo.

Comment: Si esta usando una generación aleatoria del **password** no te lo va a devolver igual siempre ahora una ver que tu lo generes y lo codifiques,  ese valor entonces si te tiene que devolver la misma codificación.

Comment: Se me crea al hacer click en el boton enviar.Pongo el jquery.

Comment: quita la palabra password del insert de mysql, y prueba

Comment: Al poner `password` en el insert te esta volviendo a encriptar los datos